# How to stop binding source to find data when i write something

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My problem is that when I write something in my textbox, my combobox clears its selection. This happens only on one specific combobox, which is databound using the code below.

```
private void FillEmployemenetType()
{
    var items = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("C", "Contract"));
    items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("P", "Permanent"));
    items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("V", "Vacation"));

    contractTypeComboBox.DataSource = items;
    contractTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
    contractTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
    contractTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

I have not fired any text change event or wrote any code for that. 
I use binding source for this window form, in case that could be the problem.

Comment: I read it twice but couldn't understand the question

Comment: @USER_NAME problem is i have a combobox and i bind this using above code . And on my windows form i use binding source for all text box and `combobox` . The problem is that when something i write on text box automatically all my `comobox` blank i need to select again the combobox . This happen only on that `combobox` that i bind with above code . Here i also clear that i have not fire any event on `textchange` on my text box so why this is happening

Comment: Well, if this is the binding code for the combobox you are clearly creating a new list and setting that as the datasource, and on top of that setting `SelectedIndex` to 0 which sets the first item as selected. You need to store what `SelectedItem` is before assigning DataSource and reset that after you set the datasource.

Comment: @Patrick So can you please give me example to how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `SelectedItem` after you set the datasource, in order to reselect the previous item.

```
private void FillEmployemenetType()
{
    KeyValuePair<string,string>? previous = null;
    if (contractTypeComboBox.DataSource != null) {
        previous = (KeyValuePair<string,string>)contractTypeComboBox.SelectedItem;
    }

    var items = new BindingList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("C", "Contract"));
    items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("P", "Permanent"));
    items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("V", "Vacation"));

    contractTypeComboBox.DataSource = items;
    contractTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
    contractTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
    //contractTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    if (previous.HasValue) {
        try {
            contractTypeComboBox.SelectedItem = previous;
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi  its give an exception on `KeyValuePair<string,string> previous = (KeyValuePair<string,string>)contractTypeComboBox.SelectedItem;`

Comment: The Exception is object reference not set an instance of object

Comment: Okay, you should be able to work out that "it doesn't work" is not enough information, and a nullreference exception doesn't say that much either. The next time, please specify *what* object is null if you can. I edited the code with what I believe was the problem.